# Angular Array to String

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering how I could convert something like:

```
$scope.foo = [
               {name: "foo1", information : "bar1" },
               {name: "foo2", information : "bar2" }
             ]
```

into a JSON string? I searched Stack Overflow earlier for this question and was advised to use `angular.toJson(obj, pretty)` which I also researched on their website, but I wasn't able to successfully do it.

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify($scope.foo)`?

Comment: JSON.stringify($scope.foo) may be? If you want to convert it to String?

Comment: `angular.toJson($scope.foo, true)` should work fine. What errors did you get? Also `angular.toJson($scope.foo)` would work since `pretty` is optional

Comment: What @charlietfl said. [_angular.toJson()_](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) has been in there for quite a while and the preferred method, as it strips any _$$_ prefixed properties, so the errors you're getting should expose where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written the following on chrome console:

```
var foo = [
      {name: "foo1", information : "bar1" },
      {name: "foo2", information : "bar2" }
]
JSON.stringify(foo);
```

the output was:
    "[{"name":"foo1","information":"bar1"},{"name":"foo2","information":"bar2"}]"

I believe that is what you want.

Comment: will include angular hashkeys if array was used in a repeater though, `angular.toJson()` strips them out

Comment: Stringify worked!!! Thank you guys for your help!

I did try it earlier but I made a very basic error; I called Stringify before I declared the array in the javascript file (yeah yeah i know i'm dumb). Still, it turned out alright!

Comment: Testing again in the chrome console, neither worked well with ng-repeat. If you wanna render your list with ng-repeat convert your json array back to javascript array with JSON.parse(foo) for example.